# cant sort active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I am a noobie and I am trying to simply get all the records in the database and display them in alphabetical order. Whenever I display the index page the records are always sorted in descending by their id. I used the console to try calling EvalTest.order("name") and again I kept getting the records sorted by their id in descending order instead of by name. Do I need to add an index on the name column to sort by it? This seems like the answer should be so easy but I can't seem to figure it out...

Here is my code:

```
User Model:

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :eval_tests

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                     format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  after_validation { self.errors.messages.delete(:password_digest) }

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Eval_Test Model:

```
class EvalTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 350 }
  default_scope order: 'eval_tests.created_at DESC'
end
```

EvalTest Controller:

```
class EvalTestsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @eval_test = EvalTest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @eval_test = EvalTest.new
  end

  def index
    @eval_tests = EvalTest.order("name")
  end

  def create
    @eval_test = current_user.eval_tests.build(params[:eval_test])
    if @eval_test.save
      flash[:success] = "Nouveau test cree!"
      redirect_to @eval_test
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Evaluation Test index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Index des tests') %>
<h1>Index des tests</h1>

<ul class="eval_tests">
  <% @eval_tests.each do |eval_test| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to eval_test.name, eval_test %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is a general concept, which apply to other languages and libraries/frameworks. You should have tagged it better to get better visibility and proper assistance. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have used default scope in your model. Try
`@eval_tests = EvalTest.reorder("name")`
This should solve your issue.